# Horizontal analog of a meridian?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, terminology, analogy

The lines going from pole to pole of the earth are *meridians*.

I know that the horizontal lines of latitude can be called "parallels." Is there another word for these?

Comment: Parallels of latitude are not analogs of meridians of longitude. Parallels vary in diameter, and therefore length on the surface; parallels near a pole are very short, for instance; but only the Equator is a great circle, like all meridians. A great circle is a circle on the surface of the sphere (like the equator on Earth) that has the same center as the sphere does. They don't have to go through the poles, though; great circles can be on any sphere, and only rotating spheres have poles.

Comment: @JohnLawler Actually, a meridian is _half_ of a great circle.  For example, the prime meridian, at 0 degrees longitude, is not the same as the "international date line" (or whatever the meridian itself is called), at 180 degrees longitude.  "Meridian" is derived from the Latin word for "mid-day", so called because every point on a particular meridian experiences noon at the same moment.

Comment: True, the numbering is confusing, but there you are. We all should have moved to 4-dimensional spherical coordinates a long time ago, no doubt.

Comment: The things that run at right angles to meridians are parallels.  In the proper context "parallel" is not especially ambiguous.  Eg, the "27th parallel north" is clearly understood to mean the line circling the earth at 27 degrees north of the equator.

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't, and for very good reason. As John Lawler points out, every meridian is a [great circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle) with the same diameter and circumference<sup>1, 2</sup>. On the other hand, there is only one parallel that is a great circle: the equator. Every other parallel is not a great circle and therefore smaller than every meridian<sup>3</sup>.

A meridian is [defined](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/meridian) as passing through the poles, where the poles are the points on the surface defined by the axis of rotation. A parallel is orthogonal to all meridians and can also be called a [circle of latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_latitude) or parallel of latitude. (Maybe this term is actually what you were asking for? Were you just looking for synonyms of 'parallels' that sound as fancy as 'meridian'?) However, you will not find any meridian that is 'horizontal' because there are only one set of poles on the earth, and therefore only one direction that a meridian can be. This is the **tl;dr** of the answer: **there are no poles for parallels to pass through, so they're fundamentally different and not analogous to meridians.**

In fact, the whole concept of horizontal and vertical is a poor fit for the earth. Consider the original way we define and learn about horizontal and vertical lines.

[image: Horizontal and Vertical line segments]

The key factor is that if you turn one line 90 degrees, it becomes the opposite orientation. Now consider applying that to the earth: take a 'vertical' picture of the meridians and turn it on its side.

[image: A picture of a globe with meridians marked in the typical 'vertical' orientation][image: The same picture rotated 90 degrees left]

Which meridians have become parallels?

There are several difficulties that keep this concept from translating cleanly. The first is that we've transitioned from two to three dimensions. The second is that we've transitioned to spherical geometry (from flat, or [euclidean geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_geometry)). Hopefully that's given you an answer or enough to chew on, but if you were looking for something else, I'd be happy to cover it as well.

<sup>1</sup>: Not technically true. A meridian may be wider/longer if it goes over rough terrain (mountains stretch away from the center of the earth) or shorter if it goes over mostly ocean. If the earth were a perfect sphere, each great circle would be exactly equal, so for the sake of this answer, let's pretend the earth is perfectly round in all ways.

<sup>2</sup>: Also, a meridian is technically only half of a great circle. Witness that the [prime meridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_meridian) and [antimeridian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/180th_meridian) are opposite halves of the same great circle.

<sup>3</sup>: Also not technically true. The equator is actually longer, with a greater circumference than meridians due to the Earth's rotation [squashing](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/earth-is-not-round/) it a bit. So there are actually many parallels near the equator that are also longer than the meridians and two that are exactly the same circumference, one on either side of the equator. But see <sup>1</sup> and remember we're pretending!

Comment: Right, I am looking for a "fancy" term for a parallel. The main problem is that the term "parallel" is very generic and can lots of different things. For example, machinists use "parallels" which are a kind of setup tooling. The term "meridian", however, is very specific. I am looking for a very specific term to describe a circle of latitude.

Comment: Then I don't think you can do better than "circle of latitude" or "parallel of latitude".

Comment: The word "meridian" is also ambiguous - there is a meridian of the solar system, and the word is also used in Chinese medicine to describe paths through the body.  So, neither "meridian" or "parallel" are limited to geography.

Answer (score 0):

Until some brave soul finally discovers the East Pole, we'll all just have to accept that meridians project radially, while parallels are just that. But practically speaking coordinates are given where meridians intersect parallels, as all medians intersect all parallels, and vice versa, so they are clearly counterparts to each other, which I think was at the heart of your question. They can also be called Latitudes or Latitudinal Lines (as their counterparts are Longitudinal), which should answer the rest of it.

The spaces in between intersections are commonly known as Clicks (1KMsq in a 4-digit coordinate), at least in military nomenclature. (While we're on the subject...)